# When is a unitary operator a quantum gate?

Tags: quantum-information, unitarity

Quantum gates we use like X, Y, Z, H, CNOT, etc. are all unitary. When can an arbitrary unitary operator be considered as a quantum gate?

Comment: Laziness, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quantum gates are all unitary transformations on a state of qubits. Any unitary transformation can be considered a "gate", although the ones you mention are primitive ones from which others can be constructed. More complex ones are usually referred to as circuits. The two qubit gates, $\mathrm{H}$, $\frac{\pi}{8}$ and $\mathrm{CNOT}$ are considered universal gates, because any gate set can be constructed out of those.

You may want to take a look at [these lecture notes](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~tbrun/Course/lecture12.pdf), in particular, Lemma 12. I would also suggest getting a hold of the textbook by Nielsen & Chuang.

**Addendum**:
I said something incorrect about the Toffoli gate, which is universal for classical computation, but as Peter Shor pointed out in the comments, will not give you complex entries (both Hadamard and Toffoli are real).

Comment: Using just the Hadamard and Toffoli, you can never get any complex entries in the unitary matrices, so it's not true that any gate set can be constructed out of them.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Hopefully what I wrote is correct now.

Comment: @lionelbrits was that a guess about the gate, that you were corrected?

Comment: Just misrecalled in haste.

Comment: Note that Hadamard and Toffoli are however universal for quantum computation (see http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0205115 and http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0301040).

Comment: Thanks Norbert. This result seems to rely on a mapping of complex states into a larger set of real states. Would you agree?