# Negative of Quantum Gates and Entangled States

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer

I'm well aware that using this quantum circuit:

$\hskip2in$ [image: Quantum circuit used in the generation of EPR pairs.]
<sup>$\hskip2in$Quantum circuit used in the generation of EPR pairs.</sup>

It is possible to create entangled state of two qubits (EPR pairs), in particular:
$$\def\braket#1#2{\langle#1|#2\rangle}\def\bra#1{\langle#1|}\def\ket#1{|#1\rangle} \ket{\beta_{00}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\ket{00}+\ket{11})\\
\ket{\beta_{01}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\ket{01}+\ket{10})\\
\ket{\beta_{10}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\ket{00}-\ket{11})\\
\ket{\beta_{11}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\ket{01}-\ket{10})$$

But it seems possible to have two more entangled state resembling the EPR pairs:
$$\def\braket#1#2{\langle#1|#2\rangle}\def\bra#1{\langle#1|}\def\ket#1{|#1\rangle} \ket{\beta_{??}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\ket{10}-\ket{01})\\
\ket{\beta_{??}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\ket{11}-\ket{00})$$

Which can be generated passing the initial qubit $\ket{q_0}$ in the negative of the Hadamard gate:
$$
-H=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} -1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1  \end{pmatrix}
$$
And then in the CNOT gate as usual.

The negative Hadamard gate is an unitary operator, then I assume likely to be used as a quantum gate (as it is said [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/160405/when-is-a-unitary-operator-a-quantum-gate) and, for example in the book by Chuang and Nielsen).

The questions are two:
-Are the two latter EPR pairs legitimate entangled states? If yes, why they are not used in literature alongside the four original Bell states? If no, why?

-Is the negative of a quantum gate in turn a legitimate quantum gate? Is there a particular motivation for the use of the "classical" Hadamard gate instead of its negative?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global phases are physically irrelevant. Thus, $H$ and $-H$ are the same gate, as are $|\psi\rangle$ and $-|\psi\rangle$; for instance, the states you list are the same as two of the Bell states above up to a global minus sign.

Comment: Just a wrinkle to add (I know you know this) -- $H$ and $-H$ are identical if the entire system is two qubits, but different if we're acting on a subsystem, because the phase isn't global. Consider saying $X$ and $-X$ are identical -- true for one qubit, but if I start with $\left| \beta_00 \right\rangle$ (in the OP notation) and apply one or the other I'll end up in different Bell basis states.

Comment: @zeldredge That's a subspace, not a subsystem.  Or I don't understand what you are saying?